# radiobuttonを実装したい

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

radiobuttonを実装したいのですが、swiftにデフォルトでないのでしょうか？

検索してみた結果buttonCellを用いてsetButtonでstyleをradioButtonにするというのが出てきましたが今は無いのでしょうか？

お願いいたします。

Comment: 私の知る限り、iOSの`UIButton`が下部構造としてbuttonCellなるものを持って、そのstyleをradioButtonにする、なんてことが出来た覚えはありません。macOSの`NSButton`であれば、下部構造として`NSButtonCell`なるものが存在しますので、macOS用の記事とiOS用の記事を混同されている可能性はないでしょうか? iOSの標準UIには、他OSやWebにあるような「radio button」と言うものは存在しません。限られた選択肢の中から一つを選択すると言う場合、iOSでは「pickerを使う」「segemented controlを使う」「UITableViewの行選択機能を使う」などが[iOS標準](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/)と言うことになります。まずは、iOS標準に従ったUIにするのか、無理をしてでも他のプラットフォームに似せたUIにする(radio buttonっぽいものをアプリ側で用意する)のか決める必要があります。

Comment: ご丁寧な返信、回答ありがとうごさいます。

Answer (score 1):

標準UIであれば、SegmentedControlが同等役割をもちます。
どうしてもラジオボタンUIにしたいときはOSSを使いましょう。

cf.SSRadioButtonsController
https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController